# Find the difference between adjacent numpy array layers without loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3d numpy array, and for each "layer" (first dim) I want to find differences between this "layer" and its k predecessors.
For the example bellow, for "layer" 1: 1-0; "layer" 2: 2-1 and 2-0; "layer" 3: 3-2 and 3-1 and 3-0; "layer" 4: 4-3 and 4-2 and 4-1 e.t.c.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
m = np.random.randint(low=0, high=20, size=(8, 5, 2))

num_of_frames = m.shape[0]
part_num = m.shape[1]
dfr = 4

for frame in range(num_of_frames):
    for particle in range(part_num):
        for k in range(1, dfr):
            if frame - k <= 0:
                break
            arr = m[frame, particle, :] - m[frame - k, :, :]
```

Is there any possibility to do this without for loops, in vectorized numpy style? Hope this will speed up the calculation.

Thanks for your answers and your help.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Something like `diff_k = A[k, :, :] - A[:k, :, :]`?

Comment: like A[k, :, :] - A[k-3: k, :, :] for all k